# How To Handle Spring Transaction In Two Different Application Server

Tags: spring-transactions

As of now i have good knowledge on Spring Transaction and successfully implemented Spring transaction with one application server and transaction is working good.But  wondering about if we have two different application server at that time how to use spring transaction.As of my understanding spring transaction support only one application server with one or two datasource. Guys please give advice how to handle in this situation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's almost same, in case of two application server you need two data source object, there by two session factory and two transaction manager. while performing transaction you can always choose the transaction which you want to use.

```
For ex:  Two data sources :-
1.@Autowired @Qualifier("firstAppServerDBConnection")
DataSource oracleDataSource
2.
@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondAppServerDBConnection")
DataSource mySqlDataSource
Two Session Factory
1.
@Autowired
@Qualifier("firstAppServeroracleSessionFactory")
SessionFactory oracleSessionFactory
2.
@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondAppServermySqlSessionFactory")
SessionFactory mySqlSessionFactory
```

TWo transaction manager :

Same for transaction manager

Imp Method which help you :

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(passDataSource) -- For Dif   SessionFactory
HibernateTrasnactionManager.setSessionFactory(passSessionFactory) - For Diff   Trasnaction
```

Hope it makes some sense